# How to handle trailing slash in nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, slim

I have a slim api and an app that always adds slashes at the end of every call. 
There is no way to change the calls so I search for a way to remove the trailing slashes for all api calls.

How do I do this?

This is what I tried:

```
rewrite ^/api/(.*)/$ /v1/index.php?$args;
```

Comment: `[/]` is kinda  pointless. `[]` defines a character class, and a single-character class is redundant. all chars are already single-character classes.

Comment: Thx for the advice was trying more than slashes before so I hadn't removed the brackets

Comment: Ok redirecting now works properly. but the original problem wasn't solved by this. Or could there be a problem with the args?

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware for this.

```
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
    $uri = $request->getUri();
    $path = $uri->getPath();
    if ($path != '/' && substr($path, -1) == '/') {
        // remove trailing slash
        $uri = $uri->withPath(substr($path, 0, -1));
        $request = $request->withUri($uri);
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
});
```

See http://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/route-patterns.html for details.